# Alloy Widgets and i18n

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have multiple View xmls in my widget and am trying to keep localized strings separate from the string.xml in the main app.
How do Alloy Widgets support internationalization? Do they have their own strings.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alloy did support this, but unfortunately Titanium 5.2.0 broke it. We plan to resolve it in 5.2.1 but the just-released RC does not contain a fix yet.

Follow progress here:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20537

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's there but not yet documented. Jira tickets: [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-967) and [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIDOC-1736)

Comment: I tried putting an i18n folder under widget but get the following error:
i18n: "/Users/neo/Documents/work/FieldResidential/app/widgets/CreditCheck/i18n"
[DEBUG] :  /Users/neo/.appcelerator/install/5.2.0/package/node_modules/alloy/Alloy/commands/compile/compilerUtils.js:690
[DEBUG] :                          value = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
[DEBUG] :                                                    ^
[ERROR] :  : Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined
[DEBUG] :  at/Users/neo/.appcelerator/install/5.2.0/package/node_modules/alloy/Alloy/commands/compile/compilerUtils.js:690:33